# appfabric caching instead of querying sql server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, appfabric, appfabric-cache

I have a table in sql server which I will query many times from the .net MVC code and I want to implement appfabric cache instead of sql server query(only for this query). How do I implement this?
If the query is like- 
select address from people where id = @cid;

cid can be 1,2 or 3 which comes from the code

Comment: [This blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx) should cover most of what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need AppFabric for this scenario ?

I mean, AppFabric Caching targets high volume web sites where database is a bottleneck and local caching is no longer a good choice. Yes, it's caching but for large data and distributed scenarios. In addition, you have to install additional dedicated servers for the caching tier.

Maybe a basic MemoryCache is enough to start : Local Cache, Nothing to install, no additional servers required and built-in support in .net bcl.

Here is a basic example :

```
//Create a cache instance
ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;     

//check the cache for a specific value
if (cache.Contains("mydata"))     
{         
    //get an item from the cache
    var value=cache.Get("mydata");     
}     
else    
{     
    //load data
    var data=fetchData();
    //add an data to the cache 
    cache.Add("mydata", data);     
}
```

For caching a small piece of data and for one (or a few) web servers, it's fairly enough.

Comment: As long as you don't need to invalidate the cache remotely - and you're targeting .Net >= 4 - the [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) is indeed very useful. We have a system where we use an AppFabric cluster, falling back to a MemoryCache if the cluster is down: we have to accept that we cannot invalidate cached data for the lifetime of the MemoryCache cache, but that is acceptable in our scenario, and we use a short cache expiration in the MemoryCache to mitigate the problem.

Comment: I am just learning the basics, our application do have high volume. So we need to start with appfabric little by little.

Comment: @Nithin As I said, before jumping in AppFabric, it's costless to try MemoryCache. With a little bit of abstraciton, it's not so difficult to implement a generic cache client for MemoryCache and for AppFabric and switch between implementions with your favorite IoC. High volume is not a real problem. What is important : how many web servers do you have ? what is the db activity ?

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic what's your strategy for remote invalidation with MemoryCache? Say you have some entities cached, but they are then updated, how do you remove them from the cache? With AppFabric - and other distributed caches, of course - this is trivial, but how do you manage it with local MemoryCaches on +1 servers?

Comment: @stuartd. IT can be done with a PubSub. MemoryCache also supports invalidation through ChangeMonitor. I blogged an implementation using Redis [here](https://techblog.betclicgroup.com/2013/12/31/implementing-local-memorycache-invalidation-with-redis/) and source code is [here](https://github.com/Cybermaxs/RedisMemoryCacheInvalidation)

Comment: @Cybermaxs-Betclic why do you recommend MemoryCache? We have 3 web servers, DB activity is heavy as we have large xml data stored in tables which we want to cache.

Answer (score 0):

Whichever cache you use, you would add different cache entries for each query, using a construct of a base key and the ID as the cache key, and the return from the database as the cached value:

```
public Address GetData(int cId)
{
    const string AddressCacheKeyBase = "AddressCacheKey";
    string key = AddressCacheKeyBase + cId;

    var cachedData = cache.Get(key); 

    if (cachedData != null)
    {   
         return (Address)cachedData;      
    }

    Address address = GetAddressFromDatabase(cID);
    cache.Add(key, address);

    return address;
}
```

Comment: Can we have single key with multiple values in the cache? May be as a single object?

Comment: @Nithin you certainly can, you could use a `Dictionary<int, Address>` and have the Id as the key and the Address as the value. 

However whenever you need to add - or invalidate - a value, you need to read the Dictionary from the cache, add or update the address, then store the Dictionary back into the cache.